# PHP Mustache pass a variable to a function

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I want to pass a variable to a function:

```
{{#myFunc}}{{someVar}}{{/myFunction}}
```

This is my engine:

```
$options = [
    'helpers' => [
        'myFunc' => function($value) {
            // This works
            return 'got value: ' . $value;

            // This does not work
            return SomeClass::reformat($value);
            // It passes "{{someVar}}" to the method, not the value

            // var_dump shows
            var_dump($value); // '{{someVar}}'
        }
    ]
];
$engine = new Mustache_Engine($options);

$rendered = $engine->render('{{#myFunc}}{{someVar}}{{/myFunction}}', ['someVar' => '12345']);
```

What do I do?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a lambda, [here](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags) you can see an example:

```
//the data
$data = array(
    'someVar' => "12345",
    'myFunc' => function($var) {
        return "got Value:" . $var;
    }
);
$engine = new Mustache_Engine();
$rendered = $engine->render('{{#myFunc}}{{someVar}}{{/myFunc}}', $data);
```

the function is inside the `$data`.